# Fadeout and Fadein into the same space

Tags: jquery, css, callback, fadein, fadeout

I want to fade out #lg-image and fade in #column-left and #column-right into the same space as #lg-image was.   Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: can you post some code? It would be better for me to help You.

Comment: Here is the code I have to fade the div out.

 $("#lg_image").load(function () {
  $("#lg_image").fadeOut(3000);
  });

I need to know how to fadein a section to that exact div space I just faded out.  is this possible?

Comment: you need to post the HTML!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Give that `#lg-image` and `#column-left` and `#column-right` look a lot like [CSS ID selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) I assume you're talking about HTML/CSS with a side of JavaScript.

Also given that you're referring to your HTML elements with CSS selector syntax, you're on your way to being able to use jQuery to get the job done. jQuery offers [`fadein()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functions.

There's an [example](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/#example-1) on the `fadein()` page I linked to which demos fading something out and fading something else in the same place. What you're looking for is not so much JavaScript at that point though as the CSS which allows the two elements to occupy the same space onscreen. Take note that the CSS in the example contains a `position:absolute;` CSS property targeted to the `<div>` element, and the CSS rule targeting `<p>` specifies `position:relative;`. These are the real magic and to really get it you'll need to read some about [CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: Your awesome! That's exactly right.  I'll check out the link no.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok, no jquery needed for this!

look the example:

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aguhu/4

**SOURCE CODE:** http://jsbin.com/aguhu/4/edit

let me know!

Comment: Hi, aSeptik.

Would I put #column-left and # column-right on the html page?  If so, how would I hide it so it only shows up when #lg-image fades out?